# Less frequent/verbose notifications for hg push

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-hook

My project uses hgext.notify. Currently incoming.notify = separate messages on every changeset. Considering changegroup notify, but even that contains info about every changeset, just all in one big email.

Here's the problem:

My work style is "check in early and often".  I make many small checkins, usually on branches.  Task branches.  Eventually integrated.

My teammates do not like seeing messages for all of my checkins on my task branches.

We are considering using a history editing extension  like collapse or histedit to reduce the verbosity - but I dislike losing history.  I just want not to bother them with every individual changeset.

Q: is there a way, some configuration for an existing hook, or some alternate hg extension, that can be set up to do notifies as folllws;

1. a single message per changegroup (that's okay)
2. a single user provided message per changegroup - not just concatenation of all the branch changeset messages
3. filter out only the changest messages for, say, the trunk (the default branch in hg parlance).  I.e. leave the branch changeset messages in, but don't send email.

   (Note: my pushes typically involve several changesets on a branch, and then a merge onto default.  So it is not enough to just filter the entire changegroup in or out according to what branches are affected.)
4. diffstats not between the tip and every changest on the branch, but just between "important" changesets on the trunk (default branch) - which may be evety changest on the trunk.

Comment: I think your teammates should get over themselves. Your workflow is good practice and they shouldn’t discourage it, if anything they should adopt it. Collapsing history is absolutely the worst solution. I guess changing the notification mails is a feasible compromise, but to be honest, the whole point of small commits it to make it easier to review. Isn’t changegroup notify acceptable for them?

Comment: Changegroup notify not enoough.

Comment: @LaurensHolst Changegroup notify insufficient. It's not just the notifications - they don't want to see the checkins in hg log.

Comment: @LaurensHolst - Restricting hg log to the default branch not good enough, because that sucks in all commits on branches that feed in to the default branch. We agreed to use hg rebase --collapse (hg collapse and hg histedit crash a lot).

Comment: @LaurensHolst - But I think the real problem is hg log.  The RCS and CVS tools I used a while back - heck, I wrote some of them, rcslog-merge - could restrict you truly to seeing only commits on a particular branch.  When you did a branch merge, you might see only the commit message for the merge if you so desired (but you needed to be conscientious, and make that meaningful).  //  I.e. I think this reflects a weakness in hg log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid no such extension exists. The notify extension is just a basic way to send off emails with a little room for customization.

It sounds like you have a particular idea about what you want. I suggest you see if you can formulate it as a [revision set](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) and then simply use `hg log` in a `changegroup` hook. Pipe the output to `mail` and you've got yourself a very simple notify extension that you can customize to your hearts content!

What I'm saying is that the notify extension is not that complex and in many cases it can be replaced by a suitable invocation of `hg log`. You can even use a [custom template](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) for `hg log` if you want to change the output more than what `hg log -v` or `hg log --patch` does.

The tricky part (and the part that's not entirely clear from your question) is to filter out exactly the right changesets. You mention "important" changesets in point 4 above, but I'm not entirely sure what makes a changeset "important". If it is important when it's a merge from a feature branch into `default`, then something like this might be a start:

```
hg log -r "$HG_NODE:tip and children(not branch(default)) and branch(default)"
```

By taking the child changesets of the non-`default` changesets and intersecting with changesets on the `default`, we get exactly the merge points where feature branches were integrated.

I'm sorry the answer is so generic, but I think you're best off with writing a small custom shell script for what you want.

Comment: I tried to say that it is reasonable to consider every changeset on the trunk, default branch, important.

Comment: Okay, by all means — you decide what "interesting" means. My advice was basically: roll our own mini-notify extension based on your needs. The notify extension is not overly complex and can really be replaced with an invocation of `hg log`, perhaps with a suitable [template](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html). (I'll go inline some of that in the answer.)

Comment: Thanks.  Knowing that something doesn't exist is important - avoids wasting working.  I'll look at rolling my own.  Although, by the way, these guys who don't like lots of emails also don't want fine grain checkins - they want me to collapse all of the fine graon checkins for the task branches where I work with the "chck in earlier and often" philosphy to a single checkin, using hg rebase --collapse (or hg collapse or hg histedit, although the latter often break).